# Making evaluators with user-defined procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, racket, expression-evaluation, scribble

So I'm working with DrRacket and since I'm making a manual via `#lang scribble` for my procedures I'd like to put actual examples of my procedures running using `@interactions` So far I've got this part:

```
#lang scribble/manual
@(require (for-label racket))
@(require scribble/eval racket/sandbox)
@(define my-evaluator
   (parameterize ([sandbox-output 'string]
                  [sandbox-error-output 'string])
     (make-evaluator 'racket/base '(define (f) later) '(define later 5))))
```

And when I do

```
@interaction[#:eval my-evaluator]{
                                  @(f)
                                   }
```

and then I run `scribble --htmls ++main-xref-in manual.scrbl` it correctly renders as:

```
> (f)
5
```

Is there a way to use all my definitios (that are in a different file) to evaluate using scribble? I've tried changing the line 7 for :

```
(make-evaluator 'racket/base '(define (f) later) '(define later 5) #:require "mydefs.rkt")))
```

But when I try to render it, it throws something like this:

```
make-evaluator: bad requires: "mydefs.rkt"
```

I don't want to copy paste my definitions in the `make-evaluator` part (they're a lot!) any fix? Thank you racketeers!

Answer (score 0):

[asumu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898073/asumu-takikawa) from IRC #racket helped me with this. 
All I needed was to do this:

```
@(define my-evaluator
   (parameterize ([sandbox-output 'string]
                  [sandbox-error-output 'string])
     (make-base-eval #:lang 'racket '(define (f) later) 
                     '(define later 5) 
                     '(require "../man/manager.rkt"))))
```

Note that instead of using keywords I just quoted the require statement.

Using

```
@interaction[#:eval my-evaluator]{
                                  @(define man (new manager%))@(send man crear-nodo '9)
                                   }
```

Renders perfectly.

Thanks!